# Use Linq to group and organise list of data in correct order

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have the following data table and i need to group it by quarters. I basically need to show Jan totals which will be including Jan Feb Mar then i need to show Apr totals which will include Apr May Jun and so on down the list. I also need to show offpeak and years in the same order 
[image: datatable to work with]

Comment: You should include a little more information about the underlying data source. Is this Linq 2 SQL? EF? ADO? POCOs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can "groom" your data so that the months are represented as an integer number 0 - 11, then you can group them into quarters by grouping on `int(month / 3)`.  Jan(0), Feb(1), March(2) div 3 all = 0. April(3), May(4), June(5) div 3 all = 1, etc. The Quarter number (Q1, Q2, etc) is `int(month / 3) + 1`

If the months are stored in the database as strings, you'll have to write a mapping function to reduce the string name to the month number (switch statement), and pray that this app is never used or seen by anyone other than English speakers. ;>

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. i did what you said and came up with this linq   `var results2 = (from c in results
    orderby c.Month
    group c by new {Month = (c.Month -1) / 3, c.Year } into g
    select g);`